# Not able to login using python-requests modue inspite of using the proper form data

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

**Below is my form structure:**

```
<signinWidget POST https://sellercentral.amazon.in/ap/widget application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <HiddenControl(widgetToken=X2VuY29kaW5nPVVURjgmb3BlbmlkLmFzc29jX2hhbmRsZT1zY19pbl9hbWF6b24mb3BlbmlkLmNsYWltZWRfaWQ9aHR0cCUzQSUyRiUyRnNwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQlMkZhdXRoJTJGMi4wJTJGaWRlbnRpZmllcl9zZWxlY3Qmb3BlbmlkLmlkZW50aXR5PWh0dHAlM0ElMkYlMkZzcGVjcy5vcGVuaWQubmV0JTJGYXV0aCUyRj) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(rememberMe=false) (readonly)>
  <TextControl(username=)>
  <PasswordControl(password=)>
  <SubmitButtonControl(sign-in-button=) (readonly)>>
```

**Below is the code i used for logging in:**

```
import requests

payload = {
'widgetToken'   :'X2VuY29kaW5nPVVURjgmb3BlbmlkLmFzc29jX2hhbmRsZT1zY19pbl9hbWF6b24mb3BlbmlkLmNsYWltZWRfaWQ9aHR0cCUzQSUyRiUyRnNwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQlMkZhdXRoJTJGMi4wJTJGaWRlbnRpZmllcl9zZWxlY3Qmb3Blbmlk',
'rememberMe'    : 'false',
'username'      : 'not_real',
'password'      : 'not_real',
'sign-in-button': '',           
     'metadata1':'qCHSEyLKn501AMr2dZnNxcIt0M4Pri3hVLTlMVMsr1/n3Y4eoaOYMdDgcfcObHsdka8g0hFnOuCGuBsbhzZ54KmeI2WZQrYVH3PkLeYV0ge0STSzso2lw9zyPL1/vRhUW7iH14VSbg6XJc7NI5OY7pK4Cn9APiEYAbPNk/B34xnlsfUIv6uGBGnDhUuyCS2N++J1IPjkL3ozA8BuG6'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.get('https://sellercentral.amazon.in/gp/homepage.html?')
//comment**tried to capture the cookies after s.get command,but couldnt,hence hardcoded
    t=s.post('https://sellercentral.amazon.in/gp/homepage.html?', data=payload)
    r = s.get('https://sellercentral.amazon.in/gp/homepage.html?ie=UTF8&*Version*=1&*entries*=0&')
    print r.content
```

in the above code metadata and widgettoken have been hardcoded, but i have tried capturing it too, but with less success.
I would also like some help on capturing these widgettokens and metadata1 ,if they are required to be passed
I am new to python, any kind of help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The `widgetToken` in your `payload` seems to be truncated; could that be the problem?

Comment: no i just deleted the rest ,due to its length. BOTH widgetToken and metadata1 have both been cutshort due to its length

Comment: Did you try `s.post('https://sellercentral.amazon.in/ap/widget', data=payload)` (Since that is the target URL in your widget)?

Comment: yes i have tried that, it doesnt work. I have a feeling that widget token needs to be captured and it cannot be hardcoded

Comment: Try this: `m = s.get("https://sellercentral.amazon.in/gp/homepage.html", headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})` (seems that the site does not respond properly unless you specify a user agent header). Afterwards you can get the cookies using `m.cookies`, and use them in the `post` request (you may have to include the user agent header in subsequent requests as well).

Comment: I think i am already printing the response in the last line of code ryt?the output currently i am getting is the the source code of the login page,not of the page i am referring to. i think since the login isn't successfull, when i try to access the 2nd page,it is redirected to login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `User-Agent` header to your requests. That would allow you to get the cookies and proceed with the login process.

For example, `m = s.get("https://sellercentral.amazon.in/gp/homepage.html", headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})` after which you can access the cookies via `m.cookies` to be used later in the `post` request.

(Apparently this is a problem specific to your site; in my case, many of the web sites that I tried via `requests` returned cookies without having to specify the `User-Agent` header.